# Groovy getProperties() call invoking getter for non-existent attribute over 1000 times

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming

Ran into this while doing a refactor.  Calls to getProperties() were causing our CPU usage to spike.  What we discovered is that if you have a getter without an associated attribute, when you make a call to getProperties() that getter is called over 1000 times.  The fix/workaround is obvious and we know it has something to do with metaprogramming but why is this happening (what point in the groovy source)?  See groovy script code below:

```
class tester {

    int count = 0

    public getVar() {
       println count++ + " getVar() called!"
       return var
    }
}

def t = new tester()

t.getProperties()

println "done!"
```

You should see getVar() called over 1000 times.  1068 to be exact for us.

Comment: Quite odd. I just tried this in the groovy web console http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ and I see it executed 110 times.

Comment: It happens because of this line `return var`. This is actually invoking `getVar()` itself in recursion because `return var` is same as invoking `return getVar()`. It prints the count until the stack is overflowed.

Comment: `return var` is the problem.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_direct_field_access_operator (I know the `var` field isn't defined in the class).

Comment: Changin return var to return this.@var makes all the difference

Answer (score 1):

The question has probably already been answered in the comments but I dug a little deeper to also answer the "what point in the groovy source" part.

When you call `getProperties()` on the instance of `tester` Groovy will do its magic and finally call `DefaultGroovyMethods#getProperties(Object)` which (in Groovy 2.4.7) looks like this:

```
public static Map getProperties(Object self) {
    List<PropertyValue> metaProps = getMetaPropertyValues(self); // 1
    Map<String, Object> props = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(metaProps.size());

    for (PropertyValue mp : metaProps) {
        try {
            props.put(mp.getName(), mp.getValue()); // 2
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.throwing(self.getClass().getName(), "getProperty(" + mp.getName() + ")", e);
        }
    }
    return props;
}
```

First, Groovy determines the meta properties of the given object (see 1). This will return three properties:

- `var`: getter only (`getVar()`), no setter, no field
- `class`: getter only (inherited from `Object`), no setter, no field
- `count`: getter, setter (both generated by Groovy) and field

You can easily verify this by calling `t.getMetaPropertyValues()`.

Next, Groovy tries to get the current value of each property and puts it in a map (see 2). When it reaches `var`, it remembers that `var` has a getter (namely `getVar()`) and calls it. `getVar()` however, returns `var` again. For Groovy, this is the exact same property as determined in the first step. Once again, it calls its getter `getVar()` and the endless loop begins.

At some point, depending on the JVM, this results in a `StackOverflowError`, which is exactly what this site is all about :-D